# incremental garbage collection simulation using c++

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, garbage-collection

i have a project that requires me to simulate increamental garbage collection. This uses the generational algorithm combined with mark and sweep method. So far i have designed a structure as shown in the code. The problem is with allocating memory for the code. I now am using vectors. I will also need to use pointer to point at the start of the memory and end of the memory. i dont know how to do this. Please do help me with designing this.
Here is my code so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;
using std::stringstream;



string pMem, comment, sGen, val,input,id,size,inits,incs;

double pmemSize =0;

char t[10], m[256],init[10],inc[10];


struct rootset {
  double totSize;
  double *rStrtPtr;
  double *rEndPtr;
  vector<double> physicalM; /* This is the size of physical memory i need to assign*/

  struct generations {
    double totSize;
    const char *genStrtPtr;
    const char *genEndPtr; 
    int numOfGen;
    string genName;

    struct object {
      double objSize;
      const char *objStrtPtr;
      const char *objEndPtr;
      string id;
      char markBit;
      char objPtr;
    };

    struct freeList {
      double freeSpace;
      int flNumb; 
    };
  };
};
int main()
{
  int pmemSize;
  cout<<" ENter the size "<<endl;
  cin >> pmemSize;
  vector<rootset> pRootSet;
  pRootSet.push_back(rootset());
  pRootSet[0].totSize = pmemSize;
  pRootSet[0].physicalM.reserve(pmemSize);

   for (int s=0; s<pmemSize; ++s)
      pRootSet[0].physicalM.push_back(s);

  vector<double>::iterator it;

  for(it = pRootSet[0].physicalM.begin(); it!= pRootSet[0].physicalM.end(); ++it) 
      cout <<"Printing it: " <<(*it)<<endl;
}
```

My problem now,
how to point the pointer *rStrtPtr and *rEndPtr; to the first location of the physicalM (physical memory)..?
Details: The user inputs the amount of physical memory to be reserved for the simulation. Its in bytes. For simplicity ive just used int. I will be changing it to double later as the allocation can go upto 1 GB. I've created a vector called physicalM. This is the actual physical memory block. This will later get divided into generations (indicated by the sub structure generation). When the user specifies a command `(abc = alloc(50B));` i will have to create an object called abc within the lower generation and assign 50MB of its size for it. (This part i will take care later).
Any help is appreciated...

Edit: I tried using this line in the code but i get an error:

```
pRootSet[0].rStrtPtr = &(pRootSet[0].physicalM);

error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<double>*’ to ‘double*’ in assignment
```

**Edit:** Fixed it. had to initialize my rStrtPtr as a vector.

Comment: If my design needs changing also do let me know..

Comment: Here's a related question on Stack Overflow. I hope you'll find it useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474393/memory-allocation-for-incremental-garbage-collection-simulation-in-c

Comment: "I don't know how to do this. please do help me with designing this": Which part do you need help designing?

Comment: To make the pointer point at the beginning of the block. The thing is suppose the user assigns 4b of physical memory and the number of generations specified is 2, then the physical memory gets divided into 2 generations of 2B memory each. Now when the user enters a = alloc(1B); i need to allocate 1B of memory into the lower generation. And i need to display object"a" allocated memory at starting address 0, then the pointer goes to address location 2.

Comment: But with pointers, if i initialize it to 0, it means its a null pointer.

Comment: Guys… don't close a question simply because you don't *want* to answer it. That's very obnoxious to anyone who does, and might be writing an answer.

Comment: @ Potatoswatter Sorry but, Was this question closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `pRootSet[0].rStrtPtr = &(pRootSet[0].physicalM);`

should read:

```
pRootSet[0].rStrtPtr = &(pRootSet[0].physicalM[0]);
```

or

```
pRootSet[0].rStrtPtr = pRootSet[0].physicalM.data();
```

or

```
pRootSet[0].rStrtPtr = &*(pRootSet[0].physicalM.begin());
pRootSet[0].rEndPtr = &*(pRootSet[0].physicalM.end());     // this will point to the first byte AFTER the end of the buffer.
```

I'm not sure why you're storing data sizes in a `double` though.  An `unsigned long` can store up 2^32 - 1 (4294967295) which is 4GB.